# Заморочка с if

Tags: c, c++

Добрый день господа, есть некий код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int kol=0,n,ob,sum=0;
    cout<<"Enter the nubmer: ";
    cin>>n;
    if(n<0) n=-n; 
    if(n<850000000) 
    {               
        cout<<"Telo"<<endl;
    }
    else cout<<"Number too great or incorrect!\n";
}
```

Так вот, если мы вводим числа содержащие 10 и более знаков, а также буквы, то мы успешно получаем "*Number too great or incorrect!*". Но, если нам убрать строчку "**if(n<0) n=-n;**" из кода, то при вводе букв и чисел, содержащих 10+ знаков мы будем входить в цикл и получать надпись "*Telo*". **Почему так происходит и как тогда сделать правильную проверку, если ввели число превышающее 850000000 или букву(символ)?**

Comment: @naikon, это потому, что в типе int помещаются не все целые числа (поскольку этот тип представлен в памяти 32-мя двоичными разрядами).

Из /usr/include/limits.h


    /* Minimum and maximum values a `signed int' can hold.  */
    #  define INT_MIN (-INT_MAX - 1)
    #  define INT_MAX 2147483647

или из вывода программы

    INT_MIN: -2147483648 INT_MAX: 2147483647

в более привычном виде.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а что тогда происходит если ввести букву или символ, например: ввели в cin>>n букву "r", и идет условие if(r<850000000), то как ведет себя программа?

Comment: @naikon, а Вы попробуйте, потом подумайте и спросите, *правильна ли Ваша оценка* того, что увидели на экране.

Comment: Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переполнение типа. `int` чаще всего вмещает 32 бита информации, один из которых знаковый. Таким образом, переходя некий порог, число становится отрицательным (если тип signed). int обычно представляет собой 32 бита, один из которых - знаковый.
`unsigned int` отличен тем, что те же 32 бита считаются положительными, мы имеем 2^32 значений, что почти в два раза больше максимального `signed int`.

Стоит почитать о представлении типов данных в памяти компьютера. С float/double там еще интереснее.

Для очень больших целых чисел есть еще `long` и `long long` (с версиями unsigned)

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как тогда написать правильное условие, чтобы в случае ввода числа более 2147483647 или буквы(символа) выводило сообщение об ошибке(следующее после else) и не входило в тело цикла.

Comment: @Free_ze, только не в

    почти два раза

а **немного более чем в два раза** (если точно, то в два раза + 1).

Comment: Может так?

     int kol=0,ob,sum=0;
     long long n;
     cout<<"Enter the nubmer: ";
     cin>>n;
     if(n<0) n=-n; 
     if(n<850000000LL)

Comment: Помогло, работает, спасибо!

Comment: @alexlz:

    > Enter the number: 8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @VladD И что?

    #include <gmpxx.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        mpz_class n;
        cout << "Enter тхе number: ";
        cin >> n;
        if(n < 0) n = -n;
        if(n == mpz_class("8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")) cout << n*2;
        else cout << n;
        return 0;
    }

Comment: @alexlz: Подключать GMP для того, чтобы корректно распарсить `int` из строки — это как-то из пушки по воробьям. Тем более в моём cygwin'е GMP по умолчанию нету.

Comment: @VladD В вопросе было условие `if(n<0) n=-n;if(n<850000000)`. Конечно, это можно сделать и с символьными строками, но стоит ли?

А что, в наборе пакетов cygwin нет gmp? Странно. Достаточно часто используемый gnu-продукт...

Comment: @alexlz: `850000000` вполне влезает в `int32`, даже `int64` не нужен.

---
gmp там есть, но он не ставится по умолчанию => это ж надо сделать (а лень).

Answer (score 0):

Вводите строку и пробуйте распарсить её в число (надеюсь, вы знаете, как). Если не получилось — число слишком большое, или содержит нечисловые символы, или ещё что-нибудь такое.

Comment: Понял, спасибо ;)